# App to switch between video profiles in a high-DPI laptop

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution, scaling, high-dpi

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 2 Pro, which sports a high-DPI 13" 3200x1800 screen.

Since using that with normal Windows app would be impossible, it ships with "DPI scaling" in Windows set to 200%.

This works great, but in some apps it fails miserably, because text is scaled up but everything else isn't, which usually means the text falls out of its container and gets truncated.

I'm currently fixing this manually by switching between two video "profiles":

- 3200x1800 @ 200% for most things
- 1600x900 @ 100% for games, photoshop and other apps that don't deal well with scaling.

I do this manually, by changing the resolution, and then going into "Make text and other items larger or smaller" and changing the scaling.

This is a bit annoying, and I'd like to automate it. Are there any apps that would allow me to switch between these 2 modes with 1 click? Intel's video driver has video profiles and I can change the resolution, but not the scaling with it.

I'm fine with hacked solutions, like a .bat file that writes to the registry and logs me out, for example, I just want to make the process faster and make it require fewer clicks.

NOTE: I'm running Windows 8.1

Thank you!
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering that too.
All I found was a trick to create a shortcut to launch the DPI scaling control panel.

1) Right click or press and hold on an empty area on your desktop, and click/tap on New and Shortcut.

2) Copy and paste the location below into the location area, and click/tap on the Next button.
%windir%\System32\DpiScaling.exe

3) Pin to start menu/etc

Comparing registry before/after may shed light onto what changed.

Source: [from sevenforums.com/tutorials](http://www.sevenforums.com/index.php)